# Remover Caracteres de uma String (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, string

Pessoa estou com uma dúvida, preciso remover um carácter especifico de uma string no meu input, usei uma mascara para converter ele em Real, porém como ele está com virgula e ponto meu script do js não está reconhecendo aí preciso remover o ponto e virgula quando for executar minha function no js ..
Ex:

10,000.00

Remover os , .

Como posso fazer isso ? Lembrando que os números estou recebendo como string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) junto com uma [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Exemplo:

```
const str = '10,000.00'
const strNum = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
console.log(strNum) // 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta recuperar a sua string, e remover todas as ocorrências de virgula, e todas as ocorrências de ponto, substituindo pela string vazia.

É possível fazer isso usando o seguinte código:

```
const valorstr = "100,101,000.00";
const sempontoevirgula = valorstr.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\./g, "");
```

Neste exemplo, utilizamos o `/g` para substituir todas as ocorrências da virgula.

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal usei o exemplos de vocês

 `let mensal = (mensal1.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
 let resultSoma1 = (result2.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))`

Funcionou Perfeitamente obrigado ! a todos.